# MySQL queries are timing out on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, innodb

InnoDB
MySQL 5.7

Hey everyone, as the title states, the queries I've been using are timing out on **MySQL Workbench**. I'm using the same queries as I was a week ago, however instead of taking 0.5s, they are taking 15-25s.. An example is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <time column> DESC;
```

On another note, I'm using some fairly lengthy **MySQL** queries in order to gather some rough statistics from the data, these I expect to take longer, but I'm unsure if there is a better way to go about it. I should also mention that I only currently have `SELECT/SHOW` permissions.. Here is the lengthier query that is timing out:

```
SELECT DATE(<time_sent_column>) as Update_Date, 
ABS(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>))) AS AVG_Latency,
AVG((SELECT 
    ABS(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>))) 
    FROM <table_name> 
    WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>) < 10800))))
AS Total_Average_Latency,
STDDEV(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>)) as STDDEV_Latency,
AVG((SELECT 
    ABS(STDDEV(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>))) 
    FROM <table_name> 
    WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>) < 10800))))
AS Total_STDDEV_Latency,
VAR_SAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_date)) as Variance_Latency,
AVG((SELECT 
    ABS(VAR_SAMP(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>))) 
    FROM <table_name>
    WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>) < 10800))))
AS Average_Variance_Latency,
MIN(ABS((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>)))) AS Min_Latency,
MAX(ABS((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>)))) AS Max_Latency
FROM <table_name>
WHERE ((ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>)) < 10800) AND created_at > '2018-05-01')
GROUP BY DATE(<time_created_column>)
ORDER BY DATE(<time_created_column>) DESC;
```

I could break all these up, however I would prefer to have them in a single table after the query if possible.. I'm pretty new to **MySQL** and so I'm not sure if I'm able to use `JOINs` or anything of that sort with only `SELECT/SHOW` permissions..

The database is at 50% of it's connections, minimal traffic, 98.7% key efficiency, 87.5% InnoDB Buffer Usage, 0 reads/writes per sec.. Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You have long run because you scan whole table i your subqueries.

Comment: How can I limit that to only the specific data point it's calculating? I don't actually know of any other way to do it.. I want some of the results to show a result for each day, but then some such as "Average_Variance_Latency" to show a single result that is the product of the entire data set.. I've split up the daily latency values and the standard deviation/variance into separate queries, however even when I query for ONLY the total average latency I'm timing out at 30s..

Comment: do you have index on `created_at`? and also you should change this `((ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_created_column>) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<time_sent_column>)) < 10800)` to something like `time_created_column between` and then you should have index on it

Comment: How many rows in `<table>`?

Comment: ~50,000, however it turns out the solution was just a poorly set up database. I increased the timeout timer, and it was reaching 250 seconds on some queries. The problem seemed to be that we were running off the default settings still; the buffer pool size has now been increased to suit the system and it has been indexed properly. The run times have dropped down to <.25s and have stayed there for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

(In the below, I assume that `time_created` is less than `time_sent`; adjust the code if that is not a given.)

I would start with

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
    SELECT DATE(time_sent)    AS Update_Date,
           DATE(time_created) AS Created_Date,
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_sent) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created)) AS Latency
        FROM table_name
        WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_sent) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_created)) < 10800
          AND created_at > '2018-05-01';
```

and then build the query from that temp table.  The next query will need a *lot* fewer keystrokes.  And it won't need any subqueries.

(I assume `create_date` was a typo?)

(Perhaps you want `>=` in `created_at > '2018-05-01';`?)

Note that the test for `< 10800` is probably redundant in all expressions other than the `WHERE`.